# Compiz hides Komodo's calltip

Tags: compiz

Komodo Edit/IDE shows a tooltip for functions and such, but it doesn't show up when using compiz.

Only when you disable compiz does the tooltip show.
That's a problem, of course.

Does anybody know a fix?
Is saw there's a fix for tooltips in Firefox, which Komodo is based upon.

Answer (score 1):

If it is based on firefox like you said enabling the "firefox menu fix" on compiz's workarounds (found in ccsm, in case you don't have it installed) might help - or following the same tutorial you found for firefox, if it fixed it in another way

Comment: I've already enabled it, but it does not work. I guess the code only applies to firefox windows, not all XUL based windows...